# Performance pagination in ajax (dont load all)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pagination

I have a listing of 500 data in a javascript array (product name, product price, url img product etc etc).
I can easily load the full data (500 products) but the performance is also not good.
I would like to know if is it possible to use a pagination system in jquery (ajax) which load only for example 5 results per page (and not all my array).

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you mean only load 5 items from the server? If so yes of course, just pass to the server the number of items to skip/take and implement that condition in the query for the data you send back to the client.  It's nothing to do with jQuery, just basic client/server interaction.

Comment: No, i have an array with 500 rows in javascript, is it possible to load only 5 rows per page for example ? Exemple: page 1: load 5 results and dont load the 495 rows in my array.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. If you're loading 500 now, then stop doing that, and load 5 instead!  The details of _how_ to do this are very specific to your application architecture and you're unlikely to get someone to just give you code that works. But I'd start with : https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=jquery+pagination

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're building out the html at the same time, is that right? Here's a simple way of limiting the number of data rendered on the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/m0nk3y/py7gmevt/

The code looks something like this:

```
<div class="container"></div>

var $cont = $('.container');
var products = [
    { name:'A', price:'$1.00'},
    { name:'B', price:'$2.00'},
    { name:'C', price:'$3.00'},
    { name:'D', price:'$4.00'},
    { name:'E', price:'$5.00'},
    { name:'F', price:'$6.00'},
    { name:'G', price:'$7.00'},
    { name:'H', price:'$8.00'},
    { name:'I', price:'$9.00'},
    { name:'J', price:'$10.00'}
];

$.each(products, function(i, obj) {
    if (i === 5) { return false };

    $cont.append('<p><strong>'+obj.name+'</strong> - <span>'+obj.price+'</span></p>');
});
```

If this for a product you're making moving all that data into a database might be a better solution. However, if you're doing this to prototype or to test something out, which I'm assuming you are, this might help. Let me know if this is not what you're looking for, maybe you can give me more details. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. You have understand. I'm building the HTML at the same time.

Comment: Did my answer help? Or is it not what you're looking for?